# Incomplete images in Android's Webview

Tags: android, html, caching, webview

In my app I build a webview which shows a HTML5 playlist of several videos and images (stored local) in a loop. Everything works fine, but sometimes the received data seems to be too big.

In this case videos are displayed as white areas. The next loop of the playlist they are reloaded automatically and everything works reliable.

My problem are the images. They are loaded "half" so the lower part of the image is a white area. Unlike videos they only reload if I create or reload the webview.

I guess the webview has not enough time to build the cache. I there any possibility/parameter to change that?